# How to force PulseAudio to ignore a virtual sound card (VirMIDI)?

Tags: pulseaudio

I noticed the following lines in the syslog:

> pulseaudio[353168]: Failed to find a working profile.
>
> pulseaudio[353168]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card"
> (argument: "device_id="3" name="platform-snd_virmidi.0"
> card_name="alsa_card.platform-snd_virmidi.0" namereg_fail=false
> tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes
> use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no
> card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization
> failed.

[There is a way](https://jamielinux.com/blog/tell-pulseaudio-to-ignore-a-usb-device-using-udev/) to force PulseAudio to ignore a hardware sound card using something similar to the following UDEV rule:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="1852", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5110", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"`

But the sound card in question is a virtual one, and it's created when the snd-virmidi.ko kernel module is being loaded.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
...
 3 [VirMIDI        ]: VirMIDI - VirMIDI
                      Virtual MIDI Card 1
```

Unfortunately, this module is a builtin on my system (for jack purposes) and there's no way to remove it.

So how to force PulseAudio to ignore this device?

Comment: Run `pavcontrol` and disable it?

Comment: It's not visible in pavcontrol.

Comment: A/ "this module is a builtin" ? Do you mean the driver is in-kernel built ? In which case snd-virmidi.ko will never need to get loaded. B/ Do you really mean you are using pluseaudio AND jackd ?

Answer (score 0):

[The way](https://jamielinux.com/blog/tell-pulseaudio-to-ignore-a-usb-device-using-udev/) is right. PulseAudio use `udev` to detect sound cards.
To ignore a given card, we need to add a udev rule.

I guess that the `udev` rule you add is not correct, so it doesn't work.

**For example**, ignore card named `sound-ds`

1. Check card id, it is `2` here

   ```shellsession
   $ cat /proc/asound/cards
   ...
    2 [soundds        ]: sound-ds - sound-ds
                         sound-ds
   ```
2. Get `udev` info of **card2** in `/sys/class/sound/`

   ```
   $ udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/sound/card2

   looking at device '/devices/platform/sound-ds/sound/card2':
   KERNEL=="card2"
   SUBSYSTEM=="sound"
   DRIVER==""
   ATTR{id}=="soundds"
   ATTR{number}=="2"
   ATTR{power/async}=="disabled"
   ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
   ATTR{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
   ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
   ATTR{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
   ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
   ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
   ATTR{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
   ```
3. Add a `udev` rule
   Your system should have udev rules already defined in the `/lib/udev/rules.d` directory, such as `90-pulseaudio.rules`. There should also be a `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory where you can define your own rules.

   *Files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` have the highest priority*, make sure you modify the correct file.

   The attribute `ATTR{id}` in `udev` info, we will use it to match the card
   the rule is as below

   ```
   ATTR{id}=="soundds", ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"
   ```

   it means

   ```
   if ATTR{id} == "soundds" then
     ENV{PULSE_IGNORE}="1"
   endif
   ```

   PulseAudio will check the **environment variable `PULSE_IGNORE`** when loading cards. If it's set to `true`, the card is ignored.
4. Reboot your system and check

If we are lucky, the card should have gone in PulseAudio. In PulseAudio verbose log, we should see something like below, it indicates the rule takes effect.

```
[pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Ignoring /devices/platform/sound-ds/sound/card2, because marked so.
```